# LDAP simple bind parameters

Tags: ldap

I  am trying to use ldap for a   flask application .
The  app.config['LDAP_PROVIDER_URL'] = 'ldaps://appauth.corp.domain.com:636'
(I have   replaced  the  domain    for the  original  name here)

In another script in need the  following ldap details
 conn.simple_bind_s(
            'cn=%s,ou=Users,dc=corp,dc=domain,dc=com' % username,
            password
                  )

How   do I find the  OU,or can i  ignore OU and drop it  from above. Please  let me know  if other parameters  are correct. I   don't know  LDAP

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is that you bind as an application account with search privileges to locate the user account, e.g. by his email address, displayName, etc., and then use that DN to rebind using the password he supplied.